# PHPUnit and Zend Framework assertRedirectTo() issue

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I'm having an issue with assertRedirectTo() in a test I have created, below is the code I have used:

```
public function testLoggedInIndexAction() {
  $this->dispatch('/');
  $this->assertController('index');
  $this->resetResponse();
  $this->request->setPost(array(
   'type' => 'login',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => 'asdasd',
  ));
  $this->request->setMethod('POST');
  $this->dispatch('/');
  $this->assertRedirectTo('/feed/');
}
```

You log in through / (index.php/) and submit post details there and the it redirects you to /feed/ (index.php/feed/). The details I have supplied are correct and should work however I am having issues whereby PHPUnit is saying they are incorrect:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) IndexControllerTest::testLoggedInIndexAction
Failed asserting response redirects to "/feed/"

/home/public_html/mashhr/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/Constraint/Redirect.php:190
/home/public_html/mashhr/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php:701
/home/public_html/mashhr/tests/application/controllers/UserControllerTest.php:36
```

Comment: is feed an action in your indexControlleR? if yes try: $this->assertRedirectTo('/index/feed');

Comment: No it's a completely different controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@poelinca: No, it is simply a case of Zend_Test being unreliable in registering a redirect (even if it has been called correctly!)

In his case, the real app is no doubt redirecting the user properly, but the Zend_Test environment is having trouble registering properly called redirects. The best response I can think of is to omit any failing assertRedirect which actually works in the application.

This is not an optimal situation, but unless you're prepared to dig into the Zend code to see where the problem is, this may be your best bet for efficiency. This is an example of what causes unit testing to get a bad name: Having to alter code to pass tests which actually work already.

See http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7496 Which is misleadingly specific in its title: the problem relates to all redirects, especially those which must set headers and exit instead of dispatching the original controller.

For whatever reason, this behavior causes Redirects not to always fail, but to be highly unreliable instead! If anyone knows a better workaround to this problem (which is general, and probably unrelated to the OP's code) please let us know.

Comment: Also I'd like to add, if you do all of your redirecting in controller init() - say for instance you wrap Zend's Controller Action class with a base class of your own - and do them all this way:
(in init() )
if(cond) {
  return $this->redirector->gotoSimple('logout','login','default');
}
Your tests should pass if your app is working right, and fail if it isn't, as intended.

Answer (score 3):

stumbled on this question while having the same problem. I ended up doing the following:

```
$this->assertRedirect();
$responseHeaders = $this->response->getHeaders();
$this->assertTrue(count($responseHeaders) != 0);
$this->assertArrayHasKey('value', $responseHeaders[0]);
// in my case I'm redirecting to another module
$this->assertEquals('/module/controller/action', $responseHeaders[0]['value']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've responded this answer in http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Test-failing-on-AssertRedirectTo-td3325845.html#a4451217

I'm having this same issue... A possible way to assert it could be in

- [PHPUnit and Zend Framework assertRedirectTo() issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240952/phpunit-and-zend-framework-assertredirectto-issue#answer-8760184)

But the problem is there.. My example is (wich actually works if done manually):

```
// controller modules/picking/orders/product
$orderId = $this->_getParam('oId');    
if (empty($orderId)) {
    return $this->_redirect('picking/orders/browse/invalid/empty');
}

// test
$this->dispatch('picking/orders/product');
$this->assertRedirect(); // ok
$this->assertRedirectTo('picking/orders/browse'); // error
$this->assertRedirectTo('picking/orders/browse/invalid/empty'); // error
```

After I've found the error!

---

Actually, following the example above i've found that the string comparizon in my example has an error:

```
'.../public//picking/orders/browse/invalid/empty'
'.../public/picking/orders/browse/invalid/empty'
```

... fixing the preprended slash solve the problem! ;)

Answer (score 0):

So if i understand right , you wrote a test that fails ( id say this is perfect ) .

In order to make the test pass you need to debug you're app and see where the problem is , in this case you need to have a look at the actual redirection ( or eaven the post fields sent by the form ) , maybe check the routing too . I gues nobody here will be able to answer you're question unless you post the code in you're index controller/form/view and feed controller .

Comment: allso from my understanding the proper way to test a form is using mocks and stubs , check it here ( he's testing a from redirection on isValid true/false ) http://avnetlabs.com/zend-framework/tdd-with-zend-framework-mocks-and-stubs

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I had this issue today and it was caused by the `Url` class failing to build a valid url (I was passing the wrong parameters) but not reporting an error to PHPUnit (probably because PHPUnit masks the error).

Correcting the url parameters fixes the url and with it the assertion.