# PHPUnit - how to mock/stub a redirect method?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am working on a PHP Unit test where I need to test (while 100% code coverage is required) a class that implements it's own `redirect($url, $code)` method. This method calls `exit;` at the end to make sure no other code is executed after the redirect (and without this `exit;` the redirection is not done in the end...).

Now this redirect method is called in 7 different conditions which all have their own unit test case. If I run the unit tests while the `exit;` is present in the tested class, the unit tests are exited as well. Each of the test cases is testing something like:

```php
$this->assertRedirect();
$this->assertResponseStatusCode(401);
```

Therefore I need to **stub** the `redirect` method so that it set's the `Location` header as well as the status code.

Here is what I am trying to do (using the redirect method's content except that `exit;` part - but it is not working obviously):

```php
    $this->class = $this->getMockBuilder('Some\Name\Space\Class')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
    $this->class->expects($this->any())
            ->method('redirect')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function () {
                $this->response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location: /');
                $this->response->setStatusCode(401);
                $this->response->sendHeaders();
            }));
```

and what I have tried before (and didn't work as well):

```php
    $this->class = $this->getMockBuilder('Some\Name\Space\Class')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
    $this->class->expects($this->any())
            ->method('redirect')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function () {
                header('Location: /');
            }));
```

Now the purpose of the class is to redirect somewhere in 90% of code coverage (only in one case - 2 lines out of 90 - it is not redirecting) so without the possibility to stub this redirect (and without possibility to test redirects at all) the test cases would not have almost any sense for this class (which is unwilling).

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Looks like [phpunit/test_helpers](https://github.com/php-test-helpers/php-test-helpers/blob/master/README.markdown) could do the trick, but unfortunately, I am not able to install this extension to our preview and production environments where the tests are automatically run per each application deploy.

Comment: Never tested it, but I searched for assertRedirectTo and found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240952/phpunit-and-zend-framework-assertredirectto-issue

Comment: @RoyalBg And how should the answers suggesting *omit the failing redirect test* or generally for ZF1 help me in this case?

Comment: There was a comment about mocks and stubs, where a link was given, but I couldn't open it, so my research effort was blocked. http://avnetlabs.com/zend-framework/tdd-with-zend-framework-mocks-and-stubs I thought it might be helpful. If it's not, take my apologies.

Comment: I cannot open it either, so thank you for that link...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured the problem out: because the application is an MVC architecture, the `exit;` called in during the dispatch was a bad approach.

Instead of it, after the response headers are set correctly (in order to redirect) I am returning false all the way up until it is returned back to the dispatch process. In this case I do not need to call `exit;` anymore.

Unit test for this case is running smoothly without any changes needed (it was implemented before the `exit;` call in the tested class).